# WordprocessingDocument.CreateFromTemplate method creates corrupted MS Word files

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have proper .dotm template.
When I create a new file based on a template by double clicking in explorer it creates the correct file (based on this template). Created file size after save is 16Kb (without any content).

But if I want to use `.CreateFromTemplate` method in my code I cannot open a newly created .docx file in MS Word.
New file size is 207Kb (just like .dotm file). MS Word display "run-time error 5398" and not open the file.

I'm using nuget package DocumentFormat.OpenXml 2.19.0, Word 365 version  16.0.14931.20648 - 32bit and code like this:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.CreateFromTemplate(templatePath))
{
    doc.SaveAs(newFileName);
}
```

Google is silent about this error, ChatGPT says that:

*The "Run-time Error 5398" error means that the file you are trying to open is corrupted or not a valid docx file. Possible reasons for this error may be the following:*

- *The file was not saved correctly after making changes. Verify that the Save() method was called after making changes to the file.*
- *The file was saved with the wrong extension, e.g. as DOTM instead of DOCX*
- *The file was saved in an invalid format.*
- *There may have been some unhandled exceptions in your code.*

When I manually change the extension of a new file from docx to dotm, there is no error when opening, but the file does not open.

**What am I doing wrong with CreateFromTemplate method?**

Comment: Manually changing the extension does nothing other than confuse the operating system and Word. You cannot change a .docx file to a .dotm file without Word doing a Save As.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the behavior you described, using the following unit tests:

```cs
public sealed class CreateFromTemplateTests
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper _output;

    public CreateFromTemplateTests(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        _output = output;
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("c:\\temp\\MacroEnabledTemplate.dotm", "c:\\temp\\MacroEnabledDocument.docm")]
    [InlineData("c:\\temp\\Template.dotx", "c:\\temp\\Document.docx")]
    public void CanCreateDocmFromDotm(string templatePath, string documentPath)
    {
        // Let's not attach the template, which is done by default. If a template is attached, the validator complains as follows:
        // The element has unexpected child element 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main:attachedTemplate'.
        using (var wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.CreateFromTemplate(templatePath, false))
        {
            // Validate the document as created with CreateFromTemplate.
            ValidateOpenXmlPackage(wordDocument);

            // Save that document to disk so we can open it with Word, for example.
            wordDocument.SaveAs(documentPath).Dispose();
        }

        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentPath, true))
        {
            // Validate the document that was opened from disk, just to see what Word would open.
            ValidateOpenXmlPackage(wordDocument);
        }
    }

    private void ValidateOpenXmlPackage(OpenXmlPackage openXmlPackage)
    {
        OpenXmlValidator validator = new(FileFormatVersions.Office2019);
        List<ValidationErrorInfo> validationErrors = validator.Validate(openXmlPackage).ToList();

        foreach (ValidationErrorInfo validationError in validationErrors)
        {
            _output.WriteLine(validationError.Description);
        }

        if (validationErrors.Any())
        {
            // Note that Word will most often be able to open the document even if there are validation errors.
            throw new Exception("The validator found validation errors.");
        }
    }
}
```

In both tests, the documents are created without an issue. Looking at the Open XML markup, both documents look fine. However, while I don't get any runtime error, Word also does not open the macro-enabled document.

I am not sure why that happens. It might be related to your security settings.

Depending on whether or not you really need to use `CreateFromTemplate()`, you could create a .docm (rather than a .dotm) and create new macro-enabled documents by copying that .docm.

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/issues/1314) in the Open XML SDK project on GitHub.

Comment: When Word creates a new document from a .dotm it creates a macro-free document. The file created by CreateFromTemplate from a .dotm has VBA-related parts but the type specified in [Content_Types].xml for the main document  is for a regular .docx. If you change it to a .docm type  (i.e. <Override PartName="/word/document2.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabledTemplate.main+xml"/>). the document opens, but does not find its macros. CreateFromTemplate should probably be creating a .docx and should not be creating the macro-related parts and relationships.

Comment: @jonsson, thank you for your comment. I think the expected behavior would be for the Open XML SDK to create a valid macro-enabled document (.docm) with all the macros contained in the template (.dotm). The behavior you describe would at least lead to a working document, albeit without the macros. Please feel free to join the discussion in the issue linked in my answer.

Comment: @ThomasBarnekov Yes, both are possible. Incidentally the other thing I saw in the created .docx's Content_types file was that the Default content type for the .xml extension was set to a very specific type rather than the general one. It probably didn't cause a problem in that particular file but might indicate a coding error in the OpenXML library. I'll have a look at the GitHub stuff...